# C++ automobile class how to implement arrays with setter and getter

Tags: c++, arrays, getter-setter

I am practicing my c++ by making an automobile program where it asks the user to input the year make and model of a car and it will display what they inputed. Right now it works fine but it is not saving the data. I dont care if it erases once the program closes im just looking for a way to save the data in an array but i dont know how to implement that using getter and setters.

here is my code

```
//  automobile.cpp
//  cplusplusproject
//
//  Created by Alexander  on 2/2/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Alexander. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class automobile
{
public:
    // Constructor
    automobile(int year, string make, string model)
    {
        setcarYear(year);
        setcarMake(make);
        setcarModel(model);
    } //  end of constructor

    void setcarYear(int year)
    {
        carYear = year;
    }

    int getcarYear()
    {
        return carYear;
    }

    void setcarMake(string make)
    {
        carMake = make;
    }

    string getcarMake()
    {
        return carMake;
    }

    void setcarModel(string model)
    {
        carModel = model;
    }

    string getcarModel() { return carModel; }

    int carYear;
    string carMake;
    string carModel;
};

int main()
{
    int year;
    string make, model;
    cout << "Please enter the year of the car" << endl;
    cin >> year;

    cout << "Please enter the make of the car" << endl;
    cin >> make;

    cout << "Please enter the model of the car" << endl;
    cin >> model;

    automobile automobile(year, make, model);

    // display user info
    cout << automobile.getcarYear() << automobile.getcarMake()
         << automobile.getcarModel() << endl;
}
```

any help would be appriciated

Comment: Take a look at `std::vector` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with getters or setters.

Comment: copyrighted code. XD

Comment: It may be worthy of notice for the author of this post to review the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) specifically this section in section (3): _"is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license"_ before they post copyrighted code on Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: BTW. All `setSomething` and `getSomething` functions are not necessary in this example.

Comment: If your getters and setters don't actually do anything but to change the value, consider to make the member public.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<automobile> autos;
autos.push_pack(automobile)
```

this creates a vector and adds the autombile to it

Answer (score 0):

To save your data into the array. You need a setter function for an array. Like:

```
void setArray(int index, dataType value){
      arrayName[index]= value;
}
```

or you need to take input in an array and then pass the complete array to the setter function as:

```
void setArray(dataType arr[]){
     for(int i=0;i<sizeOfArray;i++){
         arrayName[i] = arr[i];
     }
}
```

You can read more about [getter and setters for arrays](https://www.codeslehrer.com/accessor-mutator-c/).